# Create a placholder in component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components

In Angular 4, suppose you need to implement a component that allow its users to define a custom content inside it.

Example:

```
@Component({
    selector: "main-navigation",
    templateUrl: `
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav mode="side" positio="start" opened="true">
        <md-nav-list>
            <a md-list-item *ngFor="let link of links" routerLink="{{link.url}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{link.text}}</a>
        </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>

    <!-- Some placeholder for user's: content should go here -->

</md-sidenav-container>`
})
```

And the intended usage of that component would be something like that:

```
<main-navigation>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- <- this is some user content -->
</main-navigation>
```

What is the simplest way of creating such a placeholder in Angular 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would adding `<ng-content></ng-content>` to inside here be what you're looking for?

```
@Component({
    selector: "main-navigation",
    templateUrl: `
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav mode="side" positio="start" opened="true">
        <md-nav-list>
            <a md-list-item *ngFor="let link of links" routerLink="{{link.url}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{link.text}}</a>
        </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>

    <ng-content></ng-content> <!-- Some placeholder for user's: content should go here -->

</md-sidenav-container>`
})
```

This should likely add the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` along with whatever else the user puts in between `<main-navigation> </main-navigation>` tags. Not sure exactly if that's the behavior you want but if you clarify more on it, may be I could re-assess my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like it did the trick! It turned out to be that simple! I only wish it was somewhere in the official docs. There is even no link to the docs on `<ng-content></ng-content>` thing in the [top 20 Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ng-content%22&ei=M5fCWZCSHKHqjwST0rGgAw&start=0&sa=N&biw=1451&bih=719).

Comment: Nice! This [one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content) is a nice and simple read to get the idea. Hope it helps.

Comment: It is! After your answer I started figuring out whether we could create a named placeholders using `<ng-content></ng-content>` and found answers to that in this post!

Answer (score 0):

As a further development of [@amal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327165/3345644) answer.

If you want to have named placeholders, one of the possible approaches is below:

```
...
<ng-content select="content"></ng-content>
...
```

Then, you could do:

```
<main-navigation>
    <content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </content>
</main-navigation>
```

Credits to [this awesome post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content).